# Unable to establish connection to server

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have to establish connection to a server http://sand.com by calling api /api/places.
I  used NSMutableURLRequest object for above url and Authorization header.
For few times the connection was established but i did not receive data but now Connection is not getting established at all and instead didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge is called multiple times.
(The Authorization header setvalue is username:password in base64 format)
where am i going wrong?

```
NSString *urlString =
        [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://sand.com/api/places",hostURL];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL       URLWithString:urlString] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:300.0];
[theRequest setValue:@"Basic c3VyYWJoaV9taXNocmE6bWlzaHJhaml2ZQ==" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
NSURLconnections *nuc = [NSURLconnections new];
nuc.delegate = self;
[nuc connectToRequest:theRequest];

- (void)connectToRequest:(NSURLRequest*)theRequest
{
    urlConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    if (urlConnection) 
    { 
      responseData=[NSMutableData data];
    }
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:   (NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge 
{
   if ([challenge previousFailureCount] == 0)
    {  
       NikeAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    username = appDelegate.username; password = appDelegate.password;
       NSURLCredential *cred = [[NSURLCredential alloc]
                             initWithUser:username
                             password:password
                             persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone];
       [[challenge sender] useCredential:cred forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge]; 
    }
}
```